# Google App Engine: a single backend service/module?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, service, module

How does one have a simple backend module/service/backend (or whatever they decide to call it in the future since they seem to use all three interchangeably) on GAE? I need zero endpoints and no web server: I have an app that reads stuff from an endpoint and I want to store that in a database. This is not a cron job, imagine this as a `while(1){do_stuff()}`.

I am woefully confused at the GAE tutorials, which I've been reading for over three hours now. I'm just shocked at how bad the documentation is: there is a ton of information but not a single working example (e.g. the `.yaml` files of the [config file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/configuration-files) document are incomplete and don't work out of the box).

Comment: Have you looked into GCE, which gives you a VM and you can run whatever process you want to?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a module with [manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes)? You could map `/_ah/start` to a handler that does your loop. Unlike with automatic scaling your loop can continue for up to 24 hours.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I want to do, but there is no working example in the documentation. And I only found one outdated blog post about this. Can you provide more information please?